# Cannot create stored procedure mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm experiencing a serious headache while trying to create a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
create PROCEDURE insertDummyUser(rank int unsigned)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl (name, rank) VALUES ('DummyUser', rank);
END$$
```

It gives me the following error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

I just cant wrap my head around this. It looks fine to me.

I'm just starting out with these stored procedures, so any help at all is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The following stored procedure runs smoothly:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `insertDummyUser`(`p_rank` INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `tbl` (`name`, `rank`) VALUES ('DummyUser', `p_rank`);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

[image]